# Can I build F# targeting .Net framework 3.5 using Mac OS?

Tags: .net, macos, f#

I realize what I am trying to do is very specific, but I have been searching for a way to build F# libraries for use with the .NET framework 3.5 using a Mac, preferably using a command-line tool, but without much luck.

I was hoping to be able to tinker with F# to make libraries that are compatible with Unity, which editor currently does not support higher versions of the .NET framework.

Using Mono version 5.4.1 build command 'fsharpc', I have been able to build libraries, but the resulting .dll file is not backward compatible with .NET 3.5. I have also attempted to download Mono version 3.12.1, but this version in turn did not seem to have the F# build command.

The mac version of Visual Studio did not seem to support builds targeting .NET 3.5 either.

Is there anyone attempting the same thing as me, but with more success? Please let me know.

Comment: I managed to install the F# 3.1 compiler thanks to this very helpful post by Dave Thomas: http://7sharpnine.com/2012/11/03/2012-11-03-fsharp-3-in-the-mac-and-mono-world/

The output library however still does not get recognized by unity as .net 3.5 compatible. Maybe I need an older version, or modify some settings.

Seems I am getting closer, but still not there...

Comment: Does the FSharp.Core.dll itself have to be build on Mac OS? If not, I will be happy to upload the .Net35 version from my fork (https://github.com/Rodhern/fsharp/tree/net35) if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks!
I have found a FSharp.Core.dll version online that should be the correct one, so I will probably be fine on that part, but I might bother you for a version if it turns out not to work.

After moving around symlinks, installing fsharpc compiler versions, and probably corrupting one or more mono installations, I managed to build a dll file using the F# 2.0 compiler which unity does not complain about.

Now to test if I can actually call and run the code!

Comment: Hey @Jan Were you able to resolve this issue some how? I'm currently having the same problem...

Comment: @Tjofras
Yes and no. I have been able to setup an environment in which I can make libraries with f# compatible with Unity, but with some limitations:

1. Building a WebGL version will fail using any serious f# libraries. 
2. Since you will need to build libraries targetting .NET 3.5, you can only f# features and libraries up to f#2.0.

Comment: @Tjofras
Here is how I got it to work.
- Download and install mono v3.12.1 (http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.12.1/macos-10-x86/)
- If installed correctly you should be able to use the 'fsharpi' and 'fsharpc' commands from the console.
- Find and copy the UnityEngine.dll and UnityEngine.UI.dll files, copy them to your f# project and include them in your build command.
- Your build command might look something like this: 


fsharpc --target:library -r:UnityEngine.dll -r:UnityEngine.UI.dll File1.fs File2.fs

Comment: @Tjofras
Once you manage to output a dll, you can copy it to your Unity project Assets folder.
You will also need to copy the correct version of the FSharp.Core.dll, and of course any other dependencies used. I found a number of FSharp.Core versions in the mono installation, but I do not remember exactly which one I copied. The path may look something like this:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.12.1/lib/mono/gac/FSharp.Core/{some_number}/FSharp.Core.dll

Comment: @Tjofras
I might summarize this somewhere I do not have character limits and actually understand the markdown!

Let me know how it works for you and what you are making! If you need inspiration or examples, here's my hobby project I am working on now:
https://github.com/nanaki04/chess_plus_client

Although it's not working yet, you might have a peek at the code.